# VB.NET match whole word and replace

Tags: vb.net, string, .net-2.0, replace

I'm trying to replace a string with another but the problem is that the string is matching some other string partially.

For e.g. -

```
Dim x as String = "I am Soham"
x = x.Replace("am","xx")
```

After this replace I would only like the word `am` to replaced with `xx` but because my name also contains `am` its also getting replaced.

The value of x is `I xx Sohxx`. How can I stop this. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) and use the regular expression `\bam\b`. In a regular expression `\b` means "word boundary".

Comment: Brilliant. Solved it. Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I want to replace `"TRUE"` with `TRUE`. I'm not able to get the match string to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can write up like as follows also.

```
X = X.Replace(" am"," xx")
```

Comment: I think regex has more control.

Comment: Ok, you asked for replacing so I have given in the "Replace" itself